# want to update array values in vuejs using laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuex

i have an array values in update form. i need to update specific values when user change in textareas. it looks like this 
[image]

In my vuejs data objects looks like this.

```
data() {
    return {
      jobs: [],
      details: {
        basic_id: this.$route.params.id,
        work: this.jobs
      }
    };
  },
```

and my update method i wrote like this.

```
updateDetails() {
  this.loading = true;
  this.updateWorkedPlaces(this.details)
   .then(() => {
     console.log("success");
     this.loading = false;
   })
   .catch(() => {
     this.loading = false;
    });
 }
```

i pass these values it my vuex action methods.

```
async updateWorkedPlaces({ commit }, payload) {
  let job = await Api().put("works/" + payload.basic_id, payload.work);
  commit("UPDATE_WORK", job);
},
```

i pass these values to my laravel backend update function. it looks like this.

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
   $work = $request->work;
   $basic = $request->basic_id;
   foreach ($request->work as $i => $id) {
      $job = Job::findOrFail($basic);
      $job->fill(['position' => $id['position'], 'address' => $id['address']])->save();
   }
   return response()->json(['message' => 'success']);
}
```

but when i pass these values to this function it shows me this error.

```
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

how can i fix this error. anyone can help me?

Comment: Use the `dd` function to view the contents of `$request`. The `dd` function dumps the given variables and ends execution of the script:

Comment: `$request->work;` is most likely not an array.; Add a validation check

Comment: i tried this but not showing any response in network tab

Comment: @djunehor i checked the request and it sends an array

Comment: It might be an array once. But the error seem to mean it's not always an array. Hence the reason I suggested you add an input validation or a simple check `if(is_array($request->work))`

Comment: @djunehor i think my update method not passing an array. i added your code and then i could identify that.

Answer (score 0):

i figure out my problem with this function

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
  $collection = $request->all();
  for ($i = 0; $i < count($collection); $i++) {
     Job::where('id', $collection[$i]['id'])
     ->update([
          'position' => $collection[$i]['position'],
          'address' => $collection[$i]['address']
        ]);
    }
    return response()->json(['collection' => $collection]);
}
```